# What are my options for plant choices near a pressure treated retaining wall at base of backyard fence?

Tags: soil, plant-recommendations, fence, chemicals

My backyard has a fence built on a retaining wall of pressure treated wood which was built some 15 yrs ago to address height/level difference between my yard and backyard neighbor's yard. When I couldn't get a Bower vine to succeed there I dug in and explored. I found the cut off tops of the fence post had been buried there, rotted and left tunnels that water would escape through. (I filled them in.) It also left behind more chemicals. I've also had sweet peas, and morning glories fail there.

We had tons of rain this past winter, but it doesn't wash chemicals away. Existing shrubs (crepe myrtles & raphiolepis) which were there before the fence and retaining wall were replaced are doing fine, but could I expect new plantings to succeed there now? How far from the fence would be safe and not be affected by the chemicals?

Comment: Can you add photographs please? Its difficult to imagine in terms of planting area... and where are you in the world?

Comment: Need pictures and more information, such as; how did you plant the plants that didn't make it, how do you decide to water, what and how much fertilizer, mulch type on top of the soil.  I have a feeling that your preserved wood (railroad ties)? is not responsible or a worry.  Crepe Myrtle and Raphiolepsis are yummy plant species that in my experience are a bit sensitive yet they are established and doing fine.  One caveat, do not try growing vegetables or anything you want to eat in that soil.  Pictures and a bit more information.